# Using fn+F1 and fn+F2 keys change brightness instead of being used as standard function keys

Tags: keyboard

When I press `fn+Function key`, most keys are used as standard function keys. However, `F1` and `F2` still turn the brightness up and down instead of being normal function keys, even with `fn` being pressed. How can this be fixed? I'd still like my brightness keys to change the brightness, but only when `fn` is not pressed.

Comment: Does the exact opposite happen if you flip the prefs in System Prefs>Keyboard>Keyboard ? Also, check settings in Keyboard>Shortcuts>Display to make sure they're not also using the plain F-Keys.

Comment: I'm not using the plain F-Keys. I've tried to flip the prefs, and it still happens for the brightness keys, whether I hold down fn or not

Comment: did you check shortcuts?

Comment: That was the problem! Shortcuts had F1 and F2 mapped to brightness up and down.

Comment: Let me throw in a quick answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the commands aren't duplicated in Shortcuts
System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Display

[image]